# How to run a jQuery code after an angular function was loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Basically I upload an image through angular with ng-file-upload and then I want to display it and initialize a jQuery plugin called Cropper.

How can I run the jQuery code from this one? The only way it works is when I have the `$scope.loadedImage` loaded before the upload.

HTML:

`<img id="cropImage" ng-src="/{{loadedImage}}" />`

Angular

```
  $scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/photocalc/upload/file',
        method: 'POST',
        file: dataUrl,
    }).then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.result = response.status;
            $scope.loadedImage = response.data;

            jQuery('#cropImage').cropper({
              viewMode: 0,
              zoomable: false,
              dragMode: 'crop',
              guides: true,
              highlight: true,
              cropBoxMovable: true,
              cropBoxResizable: true,
              crop: function(e) {
                // Output the result data for cropping image.
                console.log(e.x);
                console.log(e.y);
                console.log(e.width);
                console.log(e.height);
                console.log(e.rotate);
                console.log(e.scaleX);
                console.log(e.scaleY);
              }
            });
        });
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status
            + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
        $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    });
}
```

Comment: If you output the response to the console what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an own directive which will observe the src attribute and init the cropper when the image loaded.

<strike>In my mind the image.onload will only fire once so you would have to remove and place a new image but try it without removing at first :)</strike>
edit: as Kevin B said this thought was wrong

```
angular.module( "$name$" ).directive( "imageCropper", [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link    : function ( $scope, $el, $attr ) {
            $attr.$observe( "src", function ( src ) {
                $el.on( "load", function () {
                    $timeout( function () {
                        $scope.result      = response.status;
                        $scope.loadedImage = response.data;

                        jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper( {
                            viewMode        : 0,
                            zoomable        : false,
                            dragMode        : 'crop',
                            guides          : true,
                            highlight       : true,
                            cropBoxMovable  : true,
                            cropBoxResizable: true,
                            crop            : function ( e ) {
                                // Output the result data for cropping image.
                                console.log( e.x );
                                console.log( e.y );
                                console.log( e.width );
                                console.log( e.height );
                                console.log( e.rotate );
                                console.log( e.scaleX );
                                console.log( e.scaleY );
                            }
                        } );
                    } );
                } );
            } );
        }
    }
} ] );
```

Comment: the load event always fires, it's just that if you don't bind the load event before the src is changed/updated, the load event will happen before you bind to it.

Comment: same on iframes?
i got that problem when i wanted to print a pdf. I loaded it into an iframe and waited for the onload event :D

Comment: Not sure about iframes, i'd assume it to be the case, but haven't extensively worked with iframes.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation you can use setTimeout and execute your jquery code after a little delay. Because it took a little bit(a very little) of time for angular to bind data in the view. So you need a little delay.

Also I've written a blog post where I've given a generic solution to call a callback function after ng-repeat finish binding all its data. You can try that as well. [Check this post here.](http://sktajbir.blogspot.com/2015/01/callback-function-after-angular.html) Let me know if you have any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: this delay gave me a lot time of research, cuz i thought i had a bug in my code when i realize, that in childscope the value changed and parentscope didn't recognize it :D

Comment: In this kind of situation I think it's better to use directive which is safe and all your code and logic work according to your need. You can try that :)

Comment: i used directives. My compiled code has 35,814 lines :D   
the compiled version has a size of 545KB for now.   
i have directives for checkboxes which will call a function when value changed. when the function in parentScope is called the value hasn't changed yet. But i pass the new value so i can take the value from arguments :)